# Facebook: Redirect URL not possible, Domain only is working

Tags: facebook-graph-api, authentication

I have read all articles found here. But my problem is another: When I try to login, it answers that the Domain is not in the settings of the app.

When I shorten the redirect url from https://www.ruhrlink.de/von_eigene_termine/ to https://www.ruhrlink.de/ it works, so the Domain IS in the Settings. But this is showing just the Homepage. But the place to work is in the index.php of Directoy "von_eigene_termine".

In both situations after Login the URL is enhanced with "?code=xyz". And the FBRLH_state is given. But when I ask just for the Access Token, the message apears. The Valid OAuth Redirect URLs is filled with both path.

Normally I should ask for something (/me for example), and if no answer is given, it should be redirected to Facebook login page, and bring me back after to the index.php. But, with this error it isnt possible. I searched the whole day about it. Maybe I am to stupid.

Comment: If you are getting this message when trying to exchange the code for a token, then this usually means you have passed a different `redirect_uri` value in that step, than was used in the login dialog call. It must be exactly the same in both cases. Using the PHP SDK? This easily happens, when you create the login dialog URL under a different URL, than what you specify as redirect URI. The SDK takes the current script URL by default, but you can explicitly pass one as parameter in the method call.

Comment: In the meantime, I have updated the sdk. The Error is gone. Thanks for the help.